# Give the probability of the event $E=\{x_1,x_2\}$

Tags: probability

We have a probability experiment with sample space $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$ with $p(x_1)=27$, $p(x_2)=32$, $p(x_3)=17$, and $p(x_4)=17$

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet?

Comment: Maybe as a hint you can use the information that the probability of something AND something else is the product of their individual probabilities and that the probability of something OR something else is the sum of their individual probabilities.

Comment: Your probability masses are greater than $1$.  This is invalid.

Comment: What exactly is $p$?